# C# use async lambda expression with return bool in Enumerable.All extension

Tags: c#, lambda, async-await

I have the following `async` method

```
private async Task<bool> HasPolicy(AuthorizationFilterContext context, string policy)
{
    var authorized = await _authorization.AuthorizeAsync(context.HttpContext.User, policy);
    return authorized.Succeeded;
}
```

I would like to use it in `Enumerable.All` and `Enumerable.Any` extension

```
var result1 = IsAndPolicy
    ? policys.All(async x => await HasPolicy(context, x))
    : policys.Any(async x => await HasPolicy(context, x));
```

But the above code gets the following error

> Error  CS4010  Cannot convert async lambda expression to delegate type 'Func<string, bool>'. An async lambda expression may return void, Task or Task, none of which are convertible to 'Func<string, bool>'.

Comment: Would you like to run these tasks concurrently or sequentially?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias, I think that in `Any` it should be sequentially and in `All` can be  concurrently

Answer (score 4):

One approach would be to *project* to an `IEnumerable<Task<bool>>`

```
var results = await Task.WhenAll(policys.Select(x => HasPolicy(context, x)));

var result1 = IsAndPolicy 
   ? results.All(x => x)                
   : results.Any(x => x);
```

The trouble with this approach, is you are processing all the items potentially needlessly.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay thanks for the edit, this was done on my phone :P

Comment: @MichaelRandall No problem :)

Comment: @MichaelRandall, what about `var result = IsAndPolicy ? policys.All((x) => HasPolicy(context, x).Result) : policys.Any((x) => HasPolicy(context, x).Result);` ? I was hoping that this approach to be somehow written using `async/await`

Comment: @roroinpho21 although that would work... its very suspect, you are executing everything sequentially, not generating the IAsyncStateMachine from the async and await pattern, and is rather smelly. Panagiotis Kanavos really has the best approach here FWIW if you can call `ToAsyncEnumerable`

Comment: @roroinpho21 beware of the `Task.Result` property. It is OK to use it only for tasks that are known to be completed. Otherwise... [problems](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html).

Answer (score 2):

Michael Randall's answer produces the correct logical result but has to evaluate all policies, even though in both cases the evaluation can be short-circuited, by the first `false` result for `All`, or the first `true` result for `Any`.

This can be avoided by converting the tasks to an `IAsyncenumerable<T>` and using [System.Linq.Async](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Async) :

```
var resultTasks=policies.ToAsyncEnumerable()
                        .Select(async x => await HasPolicy(context, x));

var result1 = await (IsAndPolicy 
                       ? resultTasks.AllAsync(x => x)                
                       : resultTasks.AnyAsync(x => x));
```

Comment: Fixed my name, upvoted as this is an awesome answer

Comment: Sorry (facepalm). I really need glasses

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos it seems that `resultTasks.AllAsync(x => x)` (All doesn't exist) is not working, the parametter is incorect. Error CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<bool>' to 'bool'

Comment: The System.Linq.Async library does not contain extension methods `All` and `Any`. At least not the version 4.1.1 that I have currently installed. It contains the `AllAsync`, `AllAwaitAsync` and `AllAwaitWithCancellationAsync` methods, and the same set for `Any`. In this case the `XXXAwaitAsync` variant is probably the most appropriate. You also need to provide async await lambdas, in order to convert from `Task<bool>` to `ValueTask<bool>`: `resultTasks.AllAwaitAsync(async x => await x)` etc.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias it's AllAsync and AnyAsync and there's no need to provide `await` in them. You're looking at the same Github sources I used. If you check the unit tests you'll see the operations don't need `await`.  The problem was created by `Select` which returned `IAsyncEnumerable<Task<bool>>`

Comment: It is worth mentioning that these operators are executing the tasks sequentially, starting the next after the completion of the previous ([source code](https://github.com/dotnet/reactive/blob/main/Ix.NET/Source/System.Linq.Async/System/Linq/Operators/All.cs))

Comment: The `AllAsync` accepts a synchronous `Func<TSource, bool>` predicate. So I don't think that it's suitable for this case.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, it seems that it works using `resultTasks.AllAsync(x => x.Result)`